# How to run a Lift-2.4 web app with sbt

Tags: eclipse, scala, jetty, sbt, lift

I'm trying to run a Lift-2.4 web app following this tutorial http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/lift24scalaide20/index.html

**The problem is how to run this app (either on jetty, tomcat or other server)?!**

I'm trying the command jetty-run, but I've got this error:

```
> jetty-run

[error] Not a valid command: jetty-run
[error] Expected '/'
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: jetty-run (similar: run)
[error] jetty-run
[error]          ^
```

And when I do container:start, I've also got an error:

```
> container:start

[error] Not a valid key: start (similar: state, target, start-year)
[error] container:start
[error] 

           ^
```

My configurations are:

The file "build.sbt" contains:

```
name := "lift-basic"

organization := "my.company"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.Default + EclipseCreateSrc.Resource

libraryDependencies ++= {
val liftVersion = "2.4"
Seq(
"net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile",
"net.liftweb" %% "lift-mapper" % liftVersion % "compile",
"org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.26" % "test",
"junit" % "junit" % "4.7" % "test",
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "0.9.26",
"org.scala-tools.testing" %% "specs" % "1.6.9" % "test",
"com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.2.147"
)
}
```

And the file ".sbt/plugins/build.sbt" contains:

```
//Eclipse Plugin

resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.0.0")
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to install the `xsbt-web-plugin` plugin for `sbt`.

Instructions are available here: https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/wiki

That should provide you with `container:start` as well as jar packaging.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest to use main "starting point" for lift apps: https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/
It's more up-to-date and it works without problems.

Comment: In fact, my question was focused on Lift-2.4 because in tutorials they said to deploy your app with this command: jetty-run
but for me it doesn't work?!
For Lift-2.5, it works great with container:start